# How to dynamically load the right markers and print them on a Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, leaflet, markers

I'm making an application that dynamically fills dropdowns from the database. You can select different tables that have different datasources in them. So one table could be just points, but unother table could have polygons. So at the moment I have the following piece of code to generate the standard markers and pop-up information. But I want to add a specific style to the markers of different tables. But I'm not sure what's the best approach to do this. I was thinking of making some variables and declaring the styles in there and then, depending on the selection of the user, use the right variable.

This is my dynamic code so far:

```
 window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson, {
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
           layer.on({
                click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                    var d = document.getElementById('tab4');
                    d.innerHTML = "";
                        for (prop in feature.properties){
                        d.innerHTML += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
                        }
                    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab4"]').tab('show');
                    console.log(d.innerHTML);
                }
            }); }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: filter: function(feature, layer) {}

Comment: Thanks fot you'r answer. I checked it out but it's not the most optimal solution for  mee. Because I'm always using `geojson` as layer because `geojson` get's filled dynamically. Isn't there a way I could use an `if.. else..` statement that checks which table is selected in my select list and than say output the corresponding marker?